# Come si dice 'as many as possible'?

Tags: grammar, translation, adjectives

Vorrei tradurre questa frase: 'He reads as many books as possible.'. Come si dice 'as many as possible' in italiano?

Comment: This question is interesting for me because I have the doubt of how to use correctly the Italian adjective "possibile" in this kind of constructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Lui) legge più libri possibili* oppure *(lui) legge più libri che può*.

Comment: Oppure, e forse anche meglio, “...più libri possibil**e**”.

Comment: Aggiungerei "quanti"  per rendere l'espressione più chiara e completa  -->  "quanti più libri possibile".

Comment: *legge più libri possibili* è errata. Una formulazione più ricercata *legge quanti più libri gli è possibile*

Comment: @mario: *legge più libri possibili* is correct according to this [article of Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_350.html).

Comment: @DaG: if I have understood correctly this [article of Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_350.html), 
*legge più libri possibili* is correct, whereas *legge più libri possibile* is not.

Comment: @OrlandoB.Manta: according to this [article of Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_350.html), it should be "quanti più libri possibili" and not "quanti più libri possibile".

Comment: @charo. Hmmm non sono d'accordo..   "Possibile" al singolare si può usare nel senso di  "[legge] quanti più libri [gli è] possibile".

Comment: @OrlandoB.Manta: If it's that way... maybe both forms are correct?

Comment: Maybe it shoud be "legge quanti più libri possibil**i**", but "legge quanti più libri gli è possibil**e**", but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @Charo:  Both forms appear to be correct, but "possibile" sounds better to my ear because I think in terms of "possible to me".  "Libri possibili"  sounds odd to me in this context, though the grammar is correct.

Comment: @OrlandoB.Manta: Forse questo argomento meriterebbe un'altra domanda.

Comment: @Charo  Il significato cambia. _cerco più amici possibili_ (plurale) significa che mi sto guardando intorno per individuare qualche persona  (più di una ma non necessariamente tante) che potrebbe essermi amico, appunto dei possibili amici. _cerco più amici possibile_ (singolare) significa che sto cercando di farmi il numero più grande di amici, appunto più grande possibile. Nel caso dei libri, la prima opzione è formulabile, ma appare bizzarra (come si legge un libro possibile?). Per la traduzione, tra le due la corretta è la seconda.

Answer (score 0):

Una possibile traduzione è "più che può", quindi in questo caso sarebbe "(Lui) legge più libri che può".