# "Legge (quanti) più libri possibile" è corretto? O invece si dovrebbe scrivere "legge (quanti) più libri possibili"?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, grammatical-number, plural, agreement

Questa domanda mi è stata suggerita dai commenti a [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/6447). Dopo aver letto questo [articolo della Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_350.html) ho pensato che la forma corretta fosse "legge (quanti) più libri possibili" perché si deve fare la concordanza tra l'aggettivo "possibile" e il sostantivo "libri". È stato detto però che la forma "legge (quanti) più libri possibile" è anche corretta perché può essere interpretata come "legge quanti più libri [gli è] possibile". Anzi, la formulazione "legge (quanti) più libri possibili", anche se corretta, suona piuttosto bizzarra all'orecchio di un italiano. Tuttavia, l'articolo della Treccani sopra citato afferma:

> È vero, però, che spesso si sente dire, nella lingua di tutti i giorni, *possibile* in enunciati simili a quello citato. Perché? Perché quel *più* non è così trasparente, riguardo al numero, e dunque tendiamo a pensarlo come a un elemento “neutro”, poiché è invariabile, e non riusciamo a immaginarlo come plurale, anche quando si accorda con un sostantivo plurale (come *amici*, nel nostro caso). Inoltre, circolano nella testa dei parlanti enunciati frequentissimi come “*non è più possibile* dire, fare qualcosa, ecc.”, o, per l'appunto, “vorrei risparmiare *il più possibile*”, o “*il più presto possibile*”, in cui sembra che l'accoppiata *più* + *possibile* (al singolare) sia l'unica corretta. Invece, quando è dovuto (cioè accompagnato a un sostantivo plurale), in un uso appropriato della lingua scritta di una certa formalità, quel *possibile* va flesso al plurale: «Cercò più amici possibili».

Questo brano mi ha fatto pensare a questa interpretazione, che non so però se sia corretta:

> Enunciati tanto frequenti come "legge quanti più libri gli è possibile" inducono a credere in modo sbagliato che la forma "legge quanti più libri possibile" sia la più corretta. Invece, come afferma l'articolo della Treccani, *in un uso appropriato della lingua scritta di una certa formalità* si dovrebbe scrivere "legge quanti più libri possibili", con l'aggettivo "possibili" al plurale.

È così?

Comment: Veramente ottima domanda, anche perché per quanto mi riguarda sento molto più spesso pronunciare la forma apparentemente sbagliata di quella apparentemente giusta.

Comment: Per quanto vale la mia opinione di non-linguista, sono in disaccordo con quell'articolo: "possibile/i" non è un aggettivo riferito al sostantivo "libri", secondo me. Non direste "Ho letto un libro possibile", vero?

Comment: Forse la chiave sta nelle parole "lingua scritta di una certa formalità...".

Comment: Ho visto che se ne parla anche [qui](http://www.achyra.org/cruscate/viewtopic.php?t=375) e se ne fa qualche citazione della *Grande grammatica italiana di consultazione*. Qualcuno di voi può consultare questa grammatica e vedere che ne dice?

Comment: @Charo, nella forum che citi vedi sopratutto l'intervento che rinvia a [superlativo](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/superlativo_%28Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano%29/), ove si discute di _Per evidenziare il valore di quantificatore universale si può posporre l’avverbiale invariabile possibile: i pendolini sono i più veloci possibile._

Comment: @mario: Curioso perché un esempio a quanto pare riportato dalla GGIC è:  *(46 a.) Bisogna, in certi casi, prendere decisioni le piú rapide possibili.*

Comment: @Charo, link? grz

Comment: @mario: Appare nel forum dell'altro mio commento.

Comment: Condordo appieno con @DaG. Considero possibile al singolare il più corretto e più logico è il più armonioso

Answer (score 1):

Il significato cambia.

(Update) Mi sembra corretta e chiara, anche se inusuale, una frase come

```
cerco più rapidamente possibile possibili amici
```

e ciò mi suggerisce le considerazioni successive.

*cerco più amici possibil**i*** (plurale) significa che mi sto guardando intorno per individuare qualche persona (più di una ma non necessariamente tante) che potrebbe essermi amico, appunto dei possibili amici.

*cerco più amici possibil**e*** (singolare) significa che sto cercando  il numero più grande di amici (attuali o potenziali a seconda del contesto), il numero appunto più grande possibile.

**ps.** ovviamente non cerco *un numero* ma *amici*, quindi   *cerco tanti amici quanti il massimo numero di amici che è possibile ricercare nelle circostanze*.

Nel caso dei libri, la prima opzione è forse esprimibile, ma appare bizzarra per ragioni non grammaticali ma semantiche, non essendo usualmente possibile leggere libri possibili :-)

Per la traduzione richiesta nel post originario, tra le due la corretta è solo la seconda, e forse non in modo ottimale.  Sulla base della discussione sotto, direi perchè si tratta di subordinazione comparativa, e non di grado comparativo di *possibile* come aggettivo.

---

**qualche altra considerazione**
(alcune delle frasi sotto elencate sono chiaramente impronunciabili, ma spero che nell'insieme aiutino a capire cosa è cosa)

```
cerco amici

cerco rapidamente amici

cerco più rapidamente di ogni altra volta amici

cerco più rapidamente possibile amici
```

in queste frasi, *più* forma il grado comparativo dell'avverbio *rapidamente*. *possibile* in qualche modo permette l'espressione del termine di paragone.

```
cerco amici

cerco alcuni/diversi/molti amici

cerco più amici

cerco più amici di quanti ne ho cercati ieri

cerco più amici di quanti (se) ne possa cercare

cerco più amici possibile
```

in queste frasi, *più* è parte della congiunziona comparativa, e ove compare sono esempi, mi sembra, di proposizione comparativa (sottointesa nel terzo caso?).  *possibile* in qualche modo sta per la subordinata comparativa, non lo vedo come aggettivo e non credo debba concordare in quantità con *amici*.

```
cerco amici

cerco amici possibili

cerco amici molto possibili

cerco amici più possibili dei tuoi

cerco amici più possibili di quelli cercati ieri

cerco amici più possibili

cerco amici possibilissimi
```

in queste frasi, *possibile* è aggettivo (amici possibili come amici potenziali), nei vari gradi, e deve concordare in genere e quantità. In alcuni casi suona strano per ragioni direi semantiche (più possibili?)

Quindi:

```
 cerco più amici possibile

 cerco amici più possibili

 cerco più amici possibili
```

nell'ultima *più* è come nella prima, non come nella seconda, ovvero l'ultima io credo debba intendersi come: *cerco più amici possibili/potenziali possibile*.

Comment: Tuttavia l'articolo della Treccani citato nella domanda afferma: «Bisogna scrivere e dire *più amici possibili*. In questo caso, *possibile* ha un valore rafforzativo nei confronti dell'aggettivo comparativo *più*.»

Comment: No, mi sembra sbagliato. _più_ è aggettivo di amici, nel senso di _indicare un numero qualsiasi diverso dall’uno_ [più](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/piu/), sotto 2.. Possibili è pure aggettivo di  amici, nel senso di potenziali. Quindi  _cerco diversi amici potenziali_ vs. _cerco il numero più grande possibile di amici_.  (ovviamente non cerco il numero, ma per capirci)

Comment: Non so, io tendo a pensare che dire che «*possibile* ha un valore rafforzativo nei confronti dell'aggettivo comparativo *più*» corrisponda alla seconda interpretazione della tua risposta. Come esempio analogo alla prima interpretazione potrei scrivere "cercò più amici *cinesi*" e, in questo caso, non penso che si possa dire che l'aggettivo *cinese* abbia un valore rafforzativo nei confronti dell'aggettivo comparativo *più*.

Comment: _più_ da solo non è un aggettivo comparativo, aiuta soltanto a formare il grado comparativo dell'aggettvo in questione: _Mario è più anziano di Marco_. Mi sembra errato considerare il rafforzare di  _più_, anzi non capisco proprio come si potrebbe rafforzare _più_.

Comment: @Charo, ti ho convinto? Sono curioso di sapere. Notte.

Comment: Veramente non mi è del tutto chiaro.

Comment: @Charo, che cosa in particolare non lo è?

Comment: Può darsi che tu abbia ragione, ma l'articolo della Treccani mi confonde.

Answer (score 0):

Premesso che "amici possibili" (al plurale) è sintagma di dubbia valenza semantica (quindi ci sono amici possibili e impossibili? libri possibili e impossibili?), e quindi sarebbe ovvio lasciare il singolare, credo che se ci fosse "meno", difficilmente diremmo: Cerco meno amici possibili. 
Strano che la risposta della Treccani sia così superficiale. E così reticente sul fatto che con "il più" di certo "possibile" rimane invariato: Cerco amici il più simpatici possibile (non *possibili) (cfr. Cerco amici simpatici il più possibile).

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: Ma “amici possibili” qui non costituisce un sintagma a sé stante, così come in “sei il miglior amico possibile” non lo costituiscono le due ultime parole (ho anche migliori amici impossibili?).

Comment: Sono d'accordo con @DaG: non credo che abbia molto senso dire "sei il miglior amico impossibile" e questo non significa che non si possa dire "sei il miglior amico possibile".

Comment: in un contesto poetico, o per esprimere una situazione paradossale, potrebbe anche dirsi "sei il miglior amico impossibile", per es. di persona che, se non ci fosse un impedimento assoluto allo sviluppo di una relazione di amicizia, potrebbe essere il miglior amico.

Answer (score -2):

Forse "legge il più libri possibile", almeno io ho sentito dire così per indicare che legge il massimo di libri riesce a leggere.